# Units for Measuring Rotation of a 3-Sphere in Four Dimensions

Tags: geometry, unit-of-measure

In four dimensions, there can be two orthogonal axes of simultaneous rotation (of two planes), right? Does that mean that we can measure such rotations of a 3-sphere in solid angles, much as we measure the rotation of a circle (or 2-sphere- still one axis) in radians? Would there be a notion of "solid revolutions" or "2-rotations"?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer.